# How to convert one row to another row in spark dataset

Tags: apache-spark, dictionary, dataset, row

For example I have one table with schema like this:

```
id int,
name string,
score int
```

I want to convert to

```
id int,
attribute struct<name string,score int>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like:

you need to write UDF like this:

```
val toArray = udf((value1 : String, value2: String) => List(value1,value2))
```

your logic should like this:

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("attribute",toArray(dff.col("name"),dff.col("score")))

df1.select("id","attribute").show()
```

Comment: Thank you! what if I want one more generic way ,say `toArray` with indefinite arguments or any type?

Comment: you can use any type of parameters and any number of parameters .

Answer (score 0):

Function "struct" can be used:

```
val originalDF = List((1, "any", 10)).toDF("id", "name", "score")
val transformed = originalDF.select($"id", struct($"name", $"score").alias("attribute"))
transformed.printSchema()
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- attribute: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- score: integer (nullable = false)
```